# Bypassing parameters in ireport 5.6.0

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I created a simple report in i-report and i added a parameter on a field salary. Now every time i click on preview i get the parameter pop-up to filter. And if the value if not correct i get a blank page. Now that's exactly what i was trying to do. However i am wondering if there's a way to enter a certain value in the parameter box to display all records. Any idea if this possible and if yes how? Thank you.

```
WHERE EMPLOYEES."SALARY" = ${P1}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your query (lets imagine that SALARY is numeric, Double). to

```
WHERE EMPLOYEES."SALARY" = $P{parameter1} OR 0=$P{parameter1}
```

and define your parameter with a `defaultValueExpression` and set attribute `isForPrompting="false"`

```
<parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Double(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

You will see **no more prompt** and display all data, if SALARY is of other class naturally you need to adjust the example accordingly.